# Show unresolved variables in html for visual studio code

Tags: html, angular, variables, visual-studio-code

How highlight or show variables in html, which I don't declare at ts ? In webshtorm it shows like errors, in red. But in Vs code I can't find answer. (For angular)

Comment: You need to install [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) or [Angular Essentials](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials) by John Papa.

Comment: And check if you are using Eslint

Comment: It doesn't help. Yes I use Eslint

Answer (score -1):

Since *TSLint* is deprecated, I suggest you to install **ESLint** Extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Update:
please, check the rule **no-undef**
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef

Update2:

> :warning: TSLint has been deprecated as of 2019. Please see this issue
> for more details: Roadmap: TSLint → ESLint. typescript-eslint is now
> your best option for linting TypeScript

Source: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/